# Multiple Lables for a Node with the neo4j-import tool

Tags: neo4j

Does anyone know how to set multiple labels for a node at import time?

In neo4j you can set multiple labels for a node.  This is useful for setting indexes on common properties.  I've always felt `is-a` taxonomies fit using labels really well.

Here's an example of how I use them:

- I've got nodes that are `restaurants` and `hotels`
- Sometimes I want to work on them separately `Match (r:restaurant)...`
- However, both restaurants and hotels are `venues` with a property `venue_id`
- Setting them to have the venue label, you can add a index `CREATE index on :venue(venue_id)`

Currently to do this, I import my restaurants and hotels and manually add the label `venue` to them both, but with non trivial graphs with lot of labels it would be ideal to just do it at import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import tool supports multiple labels in the label column (or on the command line) separated by the array delimiter is `;`.

e.g.

```
:LABEL
venue;restaurant
```